# CRM 2011- Email Exists?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, email-validation

I've so many account and contact records in CRM 2011 with their email ids. when i send email notifications to them then some emails bounce back as the particular email id doesn't exists.

Is there any way to check whether an email in MS dynamics CRM 2011 record actually a correct email id?

Comment: if the outgoing emails are tracked in crm, then the invalid responses should also get tracked in crm. one possibility is to stick a plugin on the email activity entity and check the email body for determining if it is a bounce back due to an invalid email address. i have to think there's a std something to check for. if you determine it's an invalid email, update the contact record accordingly ie probably remove the bad email and add a note of what you did

Answer (score 0):

Make an advanced find that shows contacts where email address does not contain data, so the same for accounts.

Or write a database query/application that queries the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you sending these emails using third party solution? There are also two sort of bounce response, soft bounce and hard bounce. Soft bounce is when email was refused by the server and hard bounce is when the email address is invalid (non existing).

We have a field in Contact form for email activity. When you get the hard bounce, change the status of 'Email Activity' field to hard bounced and change Allow bulk email to Do not allow. At this same time, we send email to the person who added this record and let them know that email is bounced so that they can make correction.